# Helicity is invariant under boosts along $\hat{p}$?

Tags: helicity

[In this source](http://charm.physics.ucsb.edu/people/richman/ExperimentersGuideToTheHelicityFormalism.pdf) (In Introduction, p. 1) we find the claim that the helicity operator $h=\vec{S}\cdot\hat{p}$ is invariant under rotations and boosts.

I agree that is is clearly invariant under rotations, but if I boost $p$ in such a way, that it changes direction, the the helicity does flip sign as well.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: They seems to be sloppy about this.  However, the helicity formalism is useful mostly when the daughter products of a reaction are ultrarelativistic, so the misstatement is of little practical consequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, here is the complete sentence from page 1 in the paper:

> The helicity formalism is well suited to relativistic problems bcause the helicity operator $h=\vec S\cdot\hat p$ is invariant under both rotations and boosts along $\hat p$.

The context suggests that the hat on $\hat p$ is meant to indicate a unit vector. Even if we ignore any statements about helicity, this is already in conflict with any Lorentz boost that transforms the momentum to zero: the zero vector cannot be a unit vector.

This problem goes away if the particle is massless because then its momentum is never zero, and a simple Lorentz boost along $\hat p$ cannot change the sign of $\hat p$. However, I did not see anything in the context that assumes a massless particle. Maybe the author is assuming that "helicity" implies "massless."